# Unable to add event line to xts time series (R cannot find "addEventLines" function)

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I am trying to add an event line to a time series using xts in R based on the code available in this example: http://joshuaulrich.github.io/xts/plotting_basics.html

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix) 
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)


plot(sample.xts[,4])
addEventLines(c("2007-03-20","2007-05-28"), c("foo", "bar"))
addEventLines(c("2007-03-20","2007-05-28"), c("foo", "bar"), 
              offset=1.2, pos=2, , srt=90, cex=1.5)
addEventLines(c("2007-03-20","2007-05-28"), c("foo", "bar"), 
              offset=1.2, pos=4, , srt=-90, cex=1.5)
```

but keep getting the following error message:

"Error: could not find function "addEventLines" "

Does anyone know why this is happening or could suggest an alternative way to add event lines to time series data?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to download the development version of `xts` package from github. Download the package using  `devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")` and try running the code.

Comment: Thanks - I tried installing it (after installing devtools) but the installation failed: make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
make: *** [period.max.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xts’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/xts’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/xts’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addEventLines` function seems not available in the last versions of `xts`.
Using the package `devtools`, you can download the following version of `xts` from github where the function is available:

```
devtools::install_github("R-Finance/xts")
```

Your code yields the following figure:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix) 
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
plot(sample.xts[,4])
addEventLines(c("2007-03-20","2007-05-28"), c("foo", "bar"))
addEventLines(c("2007-03-20","2007-05-28"), c("foo", "bar"), 
              offset=1.2, pos=2, , srt=90, cex=1.5)
addEventLines(c("2007-03-20","2007-05-28"), c("foo", "bar"), 
              offset=1.2, pos=4, , srt=-90, cex=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your help. I've tried installing the versions of xts that you and @Sbista have used but unfortunately the installation keeps failing."make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
make: *** [period.max.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xts’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/xts’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/xts’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)"

Comment: I'm on a mac using Rstudio. I eventually found a way to add the vertical lines by converting the xts object into a dataframe (as Ryan Peek has done here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/ryan-peek-on-using-xts-and-ggplot-for-time-series-data/ ) then using ggplot2  geom_vline

Comment: I suggest to install gfortran on your mac, it is not a "mission impossible": https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/